# ImageButton не там отображается : LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

На телефоне `imagebutton` отображается не так где должна, чего нет на эмуляторе.

```
stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
Skin skin = new Skin();
TextureAtlas buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("buttonShop/button.pack"));
skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);

//ButtonShop

ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle ImageButtonShop = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
ImageButtonShop.up = skin.getDrawable("button_shop");
ImageButtonShop.down = skin.getDrawable("button_PRESSED");

ImageButton buttonShop = new ImageButton(ImageButtonShop);
buttonShop.setSize(250, 250);
buttonShop.setPosition(417, 950);

buttonShop.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        game.setScreen(new ShopScreen(game));
    }
});
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
stage.addActor(buttonShop);
```

Comment: Возможно это из-за разницы разрешения эмулятора и вашего телефона?

Comment: @Ziens И как это можно исправить?

Comment: Ну можете почитать тут некоторые теоретические сведения https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/111560/

Comment: Обратите внимание на эту формулу pixel = dp * (density/160). Можно заменить density и 160 на ваши координаты в пикселях и "эталонное разрешение" соответственно. Просто нельзя привязываться к пикселям, т.к. у разных устройств разная плотность и разрешение экрана